# How do I create a new user in SQL Server 2012 that I can use in a connection string?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I wasn't sure if this was a SO or SU question.

I have freshly installed SQL Server 2012.

I have created a database.

I have a visual studio 2012 project, and I want to connect to the database using a connection string in my web config.

Since I only have two accounts (sa and my windows account) I want to create a new user that will only have access to this one database.

Google says, in SSMS, expand the database, right click Security and go to New User.

However, when I do this and try to create a user, I choose SQL user with login, enter a username and login name, and get the error:

> 'news_login' is not a valid login or you do not have permission

I've tried by logging into SSMS as 'sa', logging in as my windows account, and running SSMS with administrator permissions. I've tried a few different usernames, and to no avail.

I notice there is no password box, so I fear I am doing it all wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Before you add the user to the db, add the user to the server -- under the server, right click the security folder, and try it that way.  Then you can grant permissions to the appropriate databases to that user.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Before you add the user to the db, add the user to the server -- under the server, right click the security folder, and try it that way. Then you can grant permissions to the appropriate databases to that user

Comment: This worked for me! Just wanted to add that even though the user was added, my SQL login wouldn't work. I had to change a setting in Server Properties -> Security -> Enable SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode. Hope others find this useful.

Comment: Changing the Server Properties did the trick for me. After creating the user, i was still getting the error - after updating server properties, and restarting the server, it is working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 11):

Here's SQL way of doing this:

```
CREATE LOGIN NewUser   
    WITH PASSWORD = '340$Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy';  
GO  

  CREATE USER NewUser FOR LOGIN NewUser;  
GO
```

**EDIT:** As per comment by @bschipp

Another example that does not expire password would be following

```
CREATE LOGIN NewUser   
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy$#' CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
    CREATE USER NewUser FOR LOGIN NewUser;  
GO
```

[more on options you can read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql).

Comment: You can also set flags such as CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF to stop the password expiring or bypass the password policy. See here for more options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First create a global login under **Security -> Logins**

Then add the user for the selected database in **Databases -> Database -> Security -> Users**